# Cannot find controller with name NameCtrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS configured in STS (Eclipse). How we can fixed this error?

> Cannot find controller with name NameCtrl.

HTML

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJ Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
      function NameCtrl($scope){
        $scope.firstName = 'John';
        $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    First name:<input ng-model="firstName" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Last name:<input ng-model="lastName" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

From angular vs`1.3.x` you have to bind controller with module in order to use.

Like this

```
angular
   .module("app",[])
   .controller("NameCtrl",function($scope){
     $scope.firstName = 'John';
     $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
})
```

Add module name in html

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/610eoxLn/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: put your script in separate js file then link the js to the html . @user4798115

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to define an angular app first (named'myApp' here).

2.Define an angular module inside that app.

3.Define a controller inside that module.

4.Bind that module to your controller, and your controller to angulaJS app.

```
var app =  angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("NameCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Smith";
});
```